# building boost 1.64 for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2017

I can not use boost 1.64 libraries in VS2017.
Compiled here like this:

```
b2 toolset=msvc-14.1 --build-dir=.x86 --stagedir=stage_x86
```

In the studio I get such errors:

```
Error   unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
```

I do not know what to do now.
I tried to compile 64 bit and use it. --> There was a corresponding error. Ok.
I compiled like this:

```
b2
```

Exactly the same error.

```
Error   unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
```

All projects linker options:

```
/OUT:"E:\Yandex.Disk\Projects\OS\Release\OS.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"E:\Yandex.Disk\Projects\OS\Release\OS.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG:FULL /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"E:\Yandex.Disk\Projects\OS\Release\OS.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\OS.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"E:\boost_1_64_0\stage_x86\lib" /TLBID:1
```

Comment: VS2017 is not supported by Boost yet afaik

Comment: Basic survival guide is to never look at boost build errors.  And to pass to job to somebody else and [download the result](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.64.0/).  Version 14.1 is the VS2017 version.

Comment: @SteveTownsend Since version 1.64 is supported, as far as I know

Comment: Please add what's in your VS project's linker settings or what command line you're using if you're calling cl directly

Comment: Have you checked if there is a package in NuGet?

Comment: @Praetorian, ok

Comment: Are your Boost libs in `E:\boost_1_64_0\stage_x86\lib`? If yes, do you have Boost auto-linking disabled?

Comment: @Praetorian how i can disable it?

Comment: @HansPassant installed, linked, dont work. same errors have

Comment: @ChristopherPisz  nuget does not contain libraries

Comment: You usually don't want to disable it. It's enabled by default for VS. You can try adding the Boost.System library to *Additional Dependencies* in your linker settings. Of course, first make sure `E:\boost_1_64_0\stage_x86\lib` contains the Boost.System library

Comment: @Evengen Strange, because I am using boost_thread-vc141 from Nuget... Compiler: Visual Studio 2017 Platforms: Win32, x64 So, I'm going to have to disagree. It seems to me there are boost libraries in Nuget for Visual Studio 2017. https://github.com/sergey-shandar/getboost

Comment: @ChristopherPisz i have installed 'libboost_locale-vc141-mt-1_64.lib' from nuGet -- > error cannot open file 'libboost-vc141-mt-1_64.lib'

Comment: Boost 1.64 docs say that latest VC++ tested as primary compiler is 14.0, with 14.1 as an additional, whatever that means. VS2017 is 15.0. `Visual C++: 7.1, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0` http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_64_0.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is my understanding that changes by Microsoft to simplify deployment of VS2017 have caused serious problems with how Boost Build detects the toolset required to build Boost. My surmise is that this is what is preventing official support and/or causing problems. As of April 2017 it's clear that issues are still present with detecting VS2017 - see for example https://github.com/boostorg/build/issues/157 and http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/VS2017-release-vswhere-exe-td4693141.html#a4693313.  The silver lining is that Microsoft is aware and seems committed to resolving this. See https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2017/04/234552.php.

Online information suggests work rounds exist using Powershell, but are non-trivial to say the least.  Suggest anybody waiting for this follow the discussion, and voice urgency to Microsoft of resolving this for Boost 1.65.0. I am not personally trying this yet (`notNeeded  & notEnoughTime`) but I am highly interested in a resolution and will come back to update if it looks like this is properly resolved.